# SQL Server order column in Binary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column which contains values:

```
col1    
--------
123455
123456
0123456
123457
123458
```

I want to sort it like:

```
 123455
 123456
 123457
 123458
0123456
```

Which collocate should I use to order? And if there is alphabet value for this, it will be:

```
 123455
 123456
 123457
 123458
0123456
 aaabcc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by `len` followed by the column itself:

```
SELECT col1
FROM TableName
ORDER BY LEN(col1), Col1
```

Comment: what if in column, i have a value like aaabcc and sort order is 
 


    123455
    123456
    123457
    123458
  0123456
    aaabcc

Comment: Then `order by isnumeric(col), len(col), col`.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the actual data is in same format with leading zeros, then you can do :

```
order by case when left(col,1) = 0 then 1 else 0 end, col
```